# HTML SMS Link displaying error "err_unknown_url_scheme" on "SAMSUNG Galaxy S6"

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, sms, samsung-mobile

In my site I set a button action link to generate html SMS link to send SMS with body. There I set some functionality using JS. Now trying to set html sms link it working on my android set "SAMSUNG DUOS 2" and also worked "Samsung Galaxy S4" but not working some of android set like "Samsung Galaxy S6".
It displaying error

> "err_unknown_url_scheme"

My js function on sms button click is below

```
function openSMS(){
 var EmailMessage = "Can you please get the following items from Aherns:" + String.fromCharCode(13);
// remove the local storage
for (var index = 0; index < localStorage.length; index++) {

// check to see if its one of our shopping list items
if( localStorage.key(index).indexOf('ShoppingListStorage') >= 0){

  // get the key and value to add to email list
  var key = localStorage.key(index);
  var value = localStorage[key];

  EmailMessage = EmailMessage + value + String.fromCharCode(13);
} 
else {
  //alert(localStorage.key(index) + " not ShoppingListStorage ")
}
}  
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var url;

if (ua.indexOf("iphone") > -1 || ua.indexOf("ipad") > -1)
  url = "sms:;body="+EmailMessage;
else
  url = "sms:?body="+EmailMessage;

 window.location.href = url;

}
```

http://notundeal.com/aherns/ahernsshopping-v.2.html

[image]